# updated_{$meta_type}_meta not firing, but updated_post_meta is

Tags: wordpress

I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly, but I can't get the `updated_{$meta_type}_meta` hook to work. There is a `updated_post_meta` hook which runs when you save a posts meta (and possibly other times, I haven't checked). I can't find much reference to `updated_{$meta_type}_meta` apart from [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_metadata), so I don't really understand if I am even hooking it correctly, because I didn't read it properly at first and so thought it should be used like: `updated_CPT_meta`, but that didn't work, so I tried a meta key instead of the CPT.

My question is, what should $meta_type be ?

Answer (score 3):

*Of course I found this straight after I posted*

As the page at https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/meta.php#L0 states, `$meta_type Type of object metadata is for (e.g., comment, post, or user)`.

So, you should just use it as `updated_post_meta` for any CPTs also.

duh.

Comment: Kudos for answering your own question with a good explanation.